# Function input in Python is not must be unicode

Tags: python-2.7, function, unicode, initialization

I work on the following function in Python 2.7:

```
import re
text = u'Obras de recuperação (45453100-8)'
def name(text):
m = re.search(r'^(.*?)\s*\(([0-9-]+)\)$', text)
if m:
    category_name = mtranslate.translate(m.group(1).encode("utf 
    8"),"en","auto")
    category_code = m.group(2).encode("utf-8")
return(category_name, category_code)
name(text)[0]
```

the output is : `u'Recovery works'`.

My problem is that the input has to be in the form of `u''` i.e. unicode and when I tried `name(text)`,  and  `name(unicode(text))`,  both failed.

if `text = 'Obras de recuperação (45453100-8)'`

I get :  **UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 17**

All function inputs are Portueges words, and I wonder how to insert them in the function.

Comment: You need to explicitly **decode** your bytestring to Unicode. You need to specify a codec. What encoding is your bytestring using?

Comment: You really, really want to read up on how Unicode and bytestrings work, see [Ned Batchelder's really excellent *Pragmatic Unicode*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

Comment: I am using "utf-8" for encoding.

Comment: Then explicitly decode using that codec: `text.decode('utf8')` or `unicode(text, 'utf8')`.